# std::map::lower_bound with a range

Tags: c++, stl

How can I get a lower_bound in a slice of a `std::map` between two iterators (similar to `std::lower_bound`) with logarithmic complexity (similar to `std::map::lower_bound`) ?

Comment: Which C++ revision?

Comment: Logarithmic in what? `std::lower_bound` is always logarithmic in comparisons

Comment: @Caleth: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound says "The number of comparisons performed is logarithmic in the distance between first and last (At most log2(last - first) + O(1) comparisons). However, for non-LegacyRandomAccessIterators, the number of iterator increments is linear. Notably, std::set and std::multiset iterators are not random access, and so their member functions std::set::lower_bound (resp. std::multiset::lower_bound) should be preferred."

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: Any

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. `std::map` interface is not appropriate. The solution is to use a flat data structure. This can be a simple sorted `std::vector` or, more conveniently, `boost::container::flat_map`. Then, use `std::lower_bound` as usual.

Comment: Std::map is used for other reasons, I can't change it to a different one.

Comment: @AlexO this cannot be done with `std::map`. No way around. `boost::container::flat_map` is a good replacement you may consider. Otherwise, you need to rethink the algorithm.